Construction of a polynomial time algorithm
We are currently learning derandomization, which aims to transfer a probabilistic proof into a deterministic algorithm. My problem is as follows.
Given $n$, constructs in time polynomial in $n$, a family $\mathcal{F}\subset 2^{[n]}$ of $n^{10}$ subsets, where each $F\in\mathcal{F}$ contains at most $10\log n$ elements satisfying:
For every family $\mathcal{G}$ of $n$ subsets, each of cardinality $n/2$, there is an $F\in\mathcal{F}$ that intersects all such $n$ subsets.
I found the following theorem could be useful: (corollary 9.2.8 of 'probabilistic method' by N. Alon and Spencer)
Let $G=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex, $d$-regular graph with the second largest eigenvalue at most $\lambda.$ If $C\subset V$ contains $cn$ vertices and
$$(1-c)d+c\lambda\leq\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}},$$
then for every $l$, the probability that a randomly chosen walk of length $l$ in $G$ avoids $C$ is at most $2^{-l/2}.$
If we take $l=10\log n$ and $c=1/2$ and $G=K_n$, then the condition is satisfied. And the probability that a random walk avoids $C$ is $\leq2^{-l/2}=n^{-5}.$ Even $\mathcal{F}$ contains $n$ such $C$'s, the possibility that a walk intersects all of them is at least $1-n^{-4}>0.$
My questions are:

How to transform the above argument into finding a possible walk for a given $\mathcal{G}$
How to find $n^{10}$ such walks that works for all possible $\mathcal{G}$?


We discourage "here is a problem statement, I have no clue how to solve it" type problems.  Can you state where you encountered this and credit the original source?   We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find this page helpful in improving your question.
